# How do you upload a zip compressed file to OpenShift application

Tags: java, openshift, putty

I recently created an application on OpenShift[enter link description here](https://openshift.redhat.com) Online and configured SSH public key with putty client 7.9, but am unable to upload files to my application. The illustrations here [enter link description here](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/remote-connection.html#download-the-putty-installer) are not very helpful. Please someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Those docs refer to v2 which is no longer supported.  Look at the v3 docs https://docs.openshift.com/online/welcome/index.html.